# Removing tool from contenttools

Tags: javascript, content-tools

I'm trying to remove the insert video option (icon) built into contenttools from the menu.

I tried following this https://github.com/GetmeUK/ContentTools/issues/173 but getting a toolbox().tools() Cannot read property '_toolsUIs' of null error. I'm guessing tools is no longer a method for toolbox. Doe's anyone know how to remove icons from the editor menu?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var editor;
    editor = ContentTools.EditorApp.get();
    editor.toolbox()._toolsUIs['video'].disabled(true);
}
```

Comment: You can set the defaults: http://getcontenttools.com/api/content-tools#settings

Comment: @DarrenSweeney where do you create this array? Do you need to pass it into a contenttools function?

Comment: The array already exists once instantiated - you could see if `DEFAULT_TOOLS` is a property on `editor` and if it is just remove video from the array - haven't used it but it's pretty standard JS stuff by the looks of it - if you need more help please create a fiddle and will help if I can